# Mobile application testing -random testing

Tags: java

I am currently doing black box testing(random testing) by using junit and robotium.
I have problem in passing the data to the test method. 
2 files, one is the `getData.java`(read the test cases from text file and covert to array) and the other is the `testMain.java` (test method on testing the android application).

Another problem is not able to run the junit test if the test methods have argument.

this code is executable

```
public void testDisplayBlackBox() {


        //Enter 10 in first editfield
        solo.enterText(0, data1);

        //Enter 20 in first editfiel
        solo.enterText(1, "3");

        //Click on Multiply button
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");

        //Verify that resultant of 10 x 20 
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("0"));

        }
```

but if passing and argument so as to get the data, error occur, junit will skip this method

```
public void testDisplayBlackBox(string a) {

string b =a[0];


        //Enter 10 in first editfield
        solo.enterText(0, b);

        //Enter 20 in first editfiel
        solo.enterText(1, "3");

        //Click on Multiply button
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");

        //Verify that resultant of 10 x 20 
        assertTrue(solo.searchText("0"));

        }
```

Comment: `String a` and `a[0]` won't work together.

Comment: yup, the prob i am facing now is how to pass the data retrieved from the text file into the test method. Thanks